ZPL TAB function
I have an application and need advice on handling barcode and tabulator functionality, ideally using ZPL (Zebra Programming Language). Below is a revised sample of the ZPL data I'm working with:
zpl_data = """
^XA
^BY1,2,50
^FO50,70^B3N,N,80,N,N
^FD{}^FS 
^FO50,160^A0N,20,30^FD{}^FS
^FO300,20^A0N,40,40^FD{}^FS 
^XZ
""".format(combined_data, combined_data, p_type).encode('utf-8')

Could you provide guidance on how to properly implement and manage barcodes and tabulators using ZPL in this case? Any insights on optimizing this approach would be greatly appreciated. Or another methods are welcome too. Thank You.
I have already tried modifying other parts of the ZPL code, but unfortunately, that didn't yield any results. The barcode is currently generated based on the ZPL data ^FD{}^FS. What I expect is to print a barcode like CZ1234567890_Tab_10, where the tab character functions as a tabulator that can be uploaded into the system. The solution needs to handle the tab as a functional separator within the barcode.

Have you tried using the ^FH command and the ascii value for the tab key?

I tested it with notepad, works correctly. But in our system does not recognize actual tab key press. So i need advice on how to emulate the Tab key press.

If you want the end scanner to send keystrokes to the computer CZ1234567890, [Tab], 10, you need to Enable the “Function Key Emulation Mode” on your scanner, and use $I for a Horizontal Tab, or $M for a carriage return in your barcode.
So the Code 39 encoded text would be CZ1234567890$I10
